# ClassNotFoundException from libraries that use other libraries

Tags: java

An overview of the problem: I have a `CSVFile` class in a `Utils` project that uses openCSV's `CSVReader` internally to load csv files.

Now I create a new project called `MyTester` and added `Utils` onto its classpath with the intention of using the `CSVFile` to work with csv files.

This is how it looks so far

```
MyTester
  src
    Tester.java

Utils
  src
    CSVFile.java
  lib
    opencsv.jar
```

Instantiating a CSVFile and passing in a file path will have it simply load the csv file:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class CSVFile {

    public CSVFile(String filename) {
       CSVReader reader = new CSVReader( ... );
       // read CSV file
    }
}
```

This works fine.

So now I want to load a csv file in a separate project. I use the `CSVFile` as that is its purpose.

```
import CSVFile;

class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       CSVFile reader = new CSVFile("test.csv");
    }
}
```

When I run `Tester`, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` while looking for `CSVReader`. The top of the stacktrace points to the line in the `CSVFile` constructor, so at least my code is doing what I expect it to do.

I am familiar with classpath related issues where I forget to add a required jar, so when I added the required jar to `MyTester` project, it works as expected.

But I don't understand why I need to do this.

If I'm using a class or method defined in a 3rd party library, I should not have to know anything about its implementation. However in this example, my `Tester` class needs `opencsv.jar`, which doesn't make sense to me. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: If MyTester and Utils are two different project then they need the dependency jar in their classpath.

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, if `A` requires `B`, and `B` requires `C`, then `A` also needs to require `C`. This means that if `B` has been updated and now requires `D`, then `A` also needs to be updated to require `D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I'm using a class or method defined in a 3rd party library, I should not have to know anything about its implementation.

This is true when *compiling* code using a third-party library (in most cases) - if my project A depends on B.jar, which is provided by a project that in turn has a dependency on C.jar, then I don't usually need C.jar on my classpath to compile project A.

At runtime it's a different story. The first time some code in my project A accesses a method in a class from B.jar, the JVM will load they bytecode for that class from B.jar, initialize the class, and proceed to execute the method in question. Similarly, if during the course of executing the method from project B, there is a method call to a class defined in C.jar, the JVM will load that bytecode as well. So, C.jar needs to be on your classpath at runtime, but not necessarily at compile-time.

This is why tools such as Maven are so popular - they handle transitive project dependencies and automatically set up your classpath for you, based on a declarative description of your project's dependencies.

Comment: I see the flaw in my thinking: I was only looking at it from a coder's perspective (eg: mine), rather than from the perspective of the one that has to figure out how to carry out my instructions (eg: the system).